# how to use wildcard query json data from mysql

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

I am using laravel and mysql 5.7 with json.
Here is my json data from database.

```
mysql> select goods from packet_code where id=582 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
goods: 
[
 {"code": "S87719300077661", "size": "7", "loged_by": "93,xx"}, 
 {"code": "S87719300094874", "size": "9", "loged_by": "93,xx"}, 
 {"code": "S87719300112648", "size": "11", "loged_by": "93,xx"}
]
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

I tried this query;

`select * from packet_code where goods->'$[0].code'="S87719300077661;"`

It works fine and I get a result.

**But the thing is that the elements are not stored in order, it could store in second or third position.**

When I try this

`select * from packet_code where goods->'$[*].code'="S87719300077661";`
I got nothing.
Also JSON_CONTAINS works fine:

```
select *  from packet_code where JSON_CONTAINS(goods,'"S87719300077661"','$[0].code');
```

But when I use wildcard

```
 select *  from packet_code where JSON_CONTAINS(goods,'"S87719300077661"','$[*].code');
```

I got this error:

`In this situation, path expressions may not contain the * and ** tokens.`

Tried change `'$[0].code'` to `$[0 to last].code` not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

```sql
SELECT `id`, JSON_PRETTY(`goods`)
FROM `packet_code`
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(
  `goods`,
  'all',
  'S87719300077661',
  NULL,
  '$[*].code') IS NOT NULL;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43e3e25716ace90bae8fa9e31d61e89d).